# new password in .m2/settings.xml does not work

Tags: maven

I had no issue on accessing to the repository.

After my password got changed. I've created new encrypted password with `mvn --encrypt-password <new password>` and added it into the:

```
    <server>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <id>artifacts-id</id>
    </server>
```

as usual in `settings.xml`.

And also tried Update Settings & Reindex in Preferences > Maven > User Settings.

And also Maven > Update Project > Force Update of Snapshots/Release.

But still it errors out with:

> [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to code-artifacts-id (http://artifacts..../artifactory/...): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.

I've tried to access to artifact with new password on IE. it works fine as usual. I was able to download...

I think there is a file that I can delete if this kind of issue occurs but don't recall exactly what it was.

If not, can anyone point out what I may miss here?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a master pwd set in `~/.m2/security-settings.xml` as described in [Maven Tips and Tricks: Encrypting Passwords](https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-encrypting-passwords/): „[...] _to encrypt passwords in a user's Maven Settings (~/.m2/settings.xml). To do this, you must first create a master password and store this master password in a security-settings.xml file in ~/.m2/settings-security.xml._“?

Comment: Yes, I already created a master password before and it worked fine on accessing to repository with previous password. This time I've tried with new password in setting.xml and didn't work so  I've also tried to create a new master password again and recreate the password for setting.xml. still not working...